# Whether the proper NOC is required at the time of visa for UK and Europe visa?

Tags: visas

My family has planned to travel to UK and Europe and my mom & dad are in Indian railway they had applied for the NOC but the NOC took about 1 month to come so they had just get a leter feom their office that the goverment is having no objection for granting them UK and Europe visa and there is a sign of the officer with the seal so will it work but the dates are not written Can  anyone help me and we have booked our tour from thomas cook and our stay in londom is for only 3days??

Answer (score 1):

A NOC is technically not required; although it can be used to validate home ties. However, a NOC without specific details about your trip (at least the dates should be there) is not that useful - it may have the opposite effect.

Do you have all the other requirements in place?

1. Finances
2. Itinerary
3. Appointment
4. Evidence of established ties

If so, you can then submit your application.

The exact number of days you are staying in London does not matter, as even for a 3 hour stay you would need some sort of visa.